# How do I return a list of results with rxjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3, Firebase, and FirebaseAuth.  I'm trying to use the currently authenticated user to retrieve a list of objects for this user. Below is my attempt and I'm getting an error

> getContacts Error: TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I'm missing something here as this seems like it should update the `onNext` with each new piece of data.

My attempt:

```
getContacts() {
    this.contactList.length = 0;
    this.data.getAuthenticatedUserContactList().subscribe(
      (contact => {
        this.contactList.push(contact);
      }),
      (error => console.error(`getContacts Error: ${error}`))
    );
  }

getAuthenticatedUserContactList() {
    return this.afAuth.getAuthUser()
      .flatMap(user => this.database.list(`contact-lists/${user.uid}`).take(1))
      .flatMap((contactList) => {
        if (contactList && contactList.length > 0) {                
          contactList.forEach(element => {
            console.log(`ForEach: ${element.userId}`); // THIS LOGS THE IDS AS EXPECTED 
            return this.database.object(`/profiles/${uid}`, { preserveSnapshot: true }).take(1);
          });
        } else {
          return Observable.throw(new Error("No bros here"));
        }
      });
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution as per forkJoin recommendation:

```
getContacts() {
    this.contactList.length = 0;
    this.data.getAuthenticatedUserContactList().subscribe(
      (contact => {
        contact.map(userContact => {
          this.contactList.push(<UserProfile>(userContact));
        });
      }),
      (error => console.error(`getContacts Error: ${error}`))
    );
  }

  getAuthenticatedUserContactList() {
    return this.afAuth.getAuthUser()
      .mergeMap(user => this.database.list(`contact-lists/${user.uid}`).take(1))
      .mergeMap((contactList) => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(contactList.map(element => this.getProfileWithUid(element.userId).map(userProfile => userProfile.val())))
      });
  }

  getProfileWithUid(uid: string) {
    this.profileObject = this.database.object(`/profiles/${uid}`, { preserveSnapshot: true });
    return this.profileObject.take(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second `flatMap()` operator you're not returning anything when this condition is true:

```
contactList && contactList.length > 0
```

The `return` statement is inside `forEach` callback.

I don't know what's the logic of your app but the callback to `flatMap` always needs to return an Observable (or something listed here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html)

Comment: Well, I thought the 'take(1)' returns an observable: export declare function take<T>(this: Observable<T>, count: number): Observable<T>;

Comment: @AnxGotta It does return an Observable but that's not the problem. I'm talking about the second `flatMap`

Comment: I don't understand.  If the returned list has no items or is null I return an `ErrorObservable` from `Observable.throw("")`. If there are items in the list I return an Observable for each item.

Comment: No, you don't... Maybe you wanted to write something like this instead? `return contactList.map(element => {...})`? Or maybe like this: `return Observable.forkJoin(contactList.map(element => {...}))`? This will wait until all of the Observable completed.

Comment: Right, the `return` is consumed by the `foreach`. I used a `forkJoin` to solve my issue.  Updated code above to reflect the changes. Thanks for the help!